# Can Palace of Versailles be done on my last day in Paris

Tags: trains, paris, museums, versailles

We are a group of 6 friends who have a bus from Paris - Paris (Bercy Seine)-210 Quai de Bercy, 75012 Paris, at 16:20 in the evening. We will be checking out from our hotel which is near Riquet RER station.
My question is, is it a practical plan to check out from the hotel in the morning, visit the Palace of Versailles via public transport with all the luggage at 11:30 time slot, and then post the visit head to Paris - Bercy Seine bus stop and catch my bus to Amsterdam.
I think it might be too ambitious a plan since the travel time is more than an hour via the metro. Our initial thought is to use luggage storage in Versailles and then head to the bus stop.
Any information affirming the plan or on the contrary would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of luggage are we talking about? A small backpack, or large bags or suitcases? I don't think you want to carry the latter through you visit in Versailles (not even sure you could).

Comment: Consider leaving the luggage at Bercy Seine in the morning, such as [here](https://www.eelway.com/en/luggage-storage/paris/bercy-seine-bus-station) and go to Versailles from there.

Comment: If the object is to just ‘tick, we’ve been to Versailles’, this plan would achieve it. Otherwise you will be going to considerable effort, plus risking missing your departure bus if anything delays your timing, and you won’t have anything like enough time to experience the chateau, its park, and the surrounding area.

Answer (score 6):

It's definitely doable but I would not recommend it.

To be safe you will have to arrive 40mn-1h before your bus. Versailles to Bercy bus station takes around 1h30 in public transport. so you will stop your visit around 2pm.
For me that leave you with 2h30 to visit Versailles and the domain which might be too short in my opinion (although you can come early I guess and visit the garden first which doesn't require a ticket).

Please also note that [big luggage are not allowed in Versailles](https://en.chateauversailles.fr/plan-your-visit). so you'll probably have to use some luggage service. you need to account for that in time needed between leaving Versailles and going to Bercy.

```
 large baggage items are not admitted on the Estate (exceeding 55x35x25 cm)
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I got the answer to my question that it might be not worth the effort. I'm landing in Paris on 22 Sept. I think it would be better if we do the Palace of Versailles at 9:30 in the morning and the Louvre at 1 PM on the 23th Sept and keep the last day to spend at ease without running with luggage. Since the tickets to the Louvre are already booked and are not reschedulable. Opinion on this plan of action would be helpful